# MySQL, how to perform "sudo kill -9 [PID]"in terminal on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew, pid

I used homebrew to install MySQL (5.7.16), when I try to start MySQL, I got an error saying " ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/var/mysql/Lees-MacBook-Air.local.pid)

Then I entered "ps -ax | grep mysql" and then I want to kill any ongoing process on MySQL by applying "sudo kill -9 [PID]". But I don't know what should I put in [PID]? I got a line saying "kill: illegal process id: [PID]"

[Here's the notification I got under typing "ps -ax | grep mysql"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3FOZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

First: don't.

Don't `kill -9` unless you absolutely have to.

`-9` is `SIGKILL`.  It absolutely kills the process, giving the process no chance to exit gracefully if it can. With MySQL, this will tend to corrupt things, requiring you to wait on the next start for automated crash recovery to clean up the mess, *best case*.  Worst case is much worse.

Much more "polite" is `-15` -- `SIGTERM` -- *asking* the process to shutdown voluntarily, giving it time to stop under its own logic.

But also... you already have MySQL Server running on this system, under a different path, and it looks like it has been running for a while, so without any more information on why you're trying to do this, or whether it's the correct solution, the pid is the leftmost number shown on the `ps` output, on the line with `mysqld` -- not `mysqld_safe`.

You may also find that there is an error log file at /usr/local/var/mysql/Lees-MacBook-Air.local.err (that's a guess, based on the location of the un-updated pid file in the message) that is useful.